# NGINX - Server configuration with multiple interfaces

Tags: nginx, virtualbox

I'm having trouble with nginx during configuration of multiple website. I'm using multiples debian VM's on Virtualbox (Windows, not a choice).
The setup I try to do is :

-One "front" VM with 2 network interfaces, one connected to the internet (NAT), and the other on a subnetwork not connected to internet (NAT network). Nginx bind on the "internet" interface.

-Two "back" VM with apache, each one with only one interface connected to the same subnetwork than the front VM.

The front VM is getting the requests from the client and proxy pass it to the right back-VM.

The problem is that on the front VM, nginx wont redirect on the right interface and try to redirect on the internet interface.

So my question is: can we specify to nginx  wich interface to use to redirect the requests ?

Thank in advance for the answers

Answer (score 1):

Hope we are talking about `proxy_pass`, not redirect.

For that issue there is no configuration parameters in nginx. If your config file is correct, then, I guess you need to setup route from your "front" machine to "back" machines and vice-versa.

First try pinging "back" machines from "front". If it does'n work, then try to add route with `ip route` or `route`.

For example, on "front" you have external interface named eth0 and internal named eth1. IP of your "back" machine is 10.0.0.2, then you should add:

`ip route add 10.0.0.2/32 dev eth1`

Comment: You right, it's proxy pass, i edited my post. 
I can ping back machine from front, but only when I specify the right network interface to the ping command. 
By the way, the "internet" interface ip is 10.0.2.15 and the ip of the interface connected to the subnetwork is 10.0.2.9, can't it confuse nginx when it have to pass the request ?

Comment: @RaphaelWestphal Yes, it can. If you need to specify interface to ping, then you just have default route pointing on "internet" interface.

Try doing `ip route add 10.0.2.9/32 dev eth1` with `eth1` changed to name of your internal interface.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer myself, the trick was to use only one interface connected to the nat network and to do a port redirection from the physical interface to the VM inside the nat network.
For it, go to File->Preferences->Network, select your network, click on the screw driver , and then port redirection